# Using Pandas how to find the count of values that satisfies a condtn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Given dataset has no of columns and the question is to find
'How many countries have a GDP greater than the GDP of UK?'

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['S.No','Country','Population','Land_area','Median_Age','GDP','GDP_per_capita'])
```

I have just started with python and came up with code to find the GDP of UK, but not sure how to compare it with other values of GDP column

```
df2[df2.Country=='United Kingdom']["GDP"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for equality, you could do:

```
uk_gdp = df2[df2.Country=='United Kingdom']["GDP"]
df2[df2["GDP"] == uk_gdp]
```